# jquery show date 7 days less from current date

Tags: jquery

Guys I need date one week before the current date so that I could send email alerts to my customers before a week of their expiry date.

Here is the code I wrote for current date

```
  var d = new Date();

  var month = d.getMonth()+1;
  var day = d.getDate();

  var current_date = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
  ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
  ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;

  alert(current_date);
```

So I need date like current date minus a week. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Sending notification email messages is a better fit for the server-side

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var today=new Date(); 
var lastWeekDate = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - 7)));

alert(lastWeekDate);
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsq7f/1/)

If you want to format the date you can write your own function like this

```
function formatDate(d){
  function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'/'+ pad(d.getMonth()+1) +'/'+ pad(d.getDate())
}
```

and call it like this

```
var formattedDate = formateDate(lastWeekDate) // returns `2013/10/19`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
```

**EDIT**

```
var oldDate = lastWeek.getFullYear() + "/"+ lastWeek.getMonth() +"/"+lastWeek.getDate();
```

Comment: if the current date is 2014-01-01 then whatis your lastWeek output can you elaborate me

Comment: it gives all but i need like this 2013/9/26

Answer (score 0):

Using timestamp would be more efficient and easier.
7 days millisecconds: 7*24*60*1000=10080000
So if you store the users expiration date stamp t, you would only have to check:

```
if(new Date.getTime()>=t) alert("expired");
else if(new Date.getTime()+10080000>=t) alert("notification");
else alert("all good");
```